# Trouble importing libraries in Python 2.7

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, debian

I'm fairly new to Linux but really willing to understand what's going on. I usually spend a lot of time on Google trying to solve the problem myself but this time, I really don't get it.

I'm running Linux debian-pierre 3.16.0-4-686-pae #1 SMP Debian 3.16.7-ckt11-1+deb8u3 (2015-08-04) i686 GNU/Linux

Here is my problem:
When importing libraries I added myself (eg *request*, *psutil*, *serial*) in a Python script, I get :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pierre/documents/script/xbee/comm.py", line 9, in <module>
    import serial
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/serial/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from serial.serialposix import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 15, in <module>
    import sys, os, fcntl, termios, struct, select, errno, time
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/select.so: undefined symbol: _PyInt_AsInt
```

I can't import them either when running Python from the command line. 
Those modules are stored in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/`.

`sys.path` gives:

```
[
  '', 
  '/usr/local/lib/python27.zip', 
  '/usr/local/lib/python2.7', 
  '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/plat-linux3',            
  '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', 
  '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-old', 
  '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', 
  '/home/pierre/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages', 
  '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages'
]
```

so the path to the folder containing the modules is included. The thing I really don't understand is that one of the libraries in this path can be loaded while the others not. I'm totally confused.

After rebuilding my laptop I installed another version of Python 2.7 because I didn't know it was already installed with Debian. The problems started from then. It really seems like Python doesn't fetch the modules from the right place, but why?

If anyone can help it would be much appreciated.

I built myself a server (cubieboard) with Cubian on it, wrote scripts, installed those libraries, use them without a problem... So I'm REALLY confused.

Comment: BTW i do feel like  " /usr/local/lib/python27.zip " and " /home/pierre/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages  " have nothing to do here but couldn't find a way to remove them from PATH

Comment: I think you hit on the error, one I have myself - installing 2.7 onto a machine that already had 2.7 - a suggestion would be to remove both and then install the debian version (only).

Comment: How did you install those modules? `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/select.so: undefined symbol: _PyInt_AsInt`: Check if you are using the correct version of your library.

Comment: Hi Kevin, I thought about this but won't removing the native debian python crash the system ?                                                                                                                 Hi multivac , I installed them downloading them and python setup.py install. How can i check that i'm using the correct version ?

Comment: ' pip freeze ' doesn't work i get several errors like this   File "/usr/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>                                                                                                                                                           
    load_entry_point('pip==1.5.6', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()